# What does "that it be" mean?

Tags: meaning

The following example is adapted from another [ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/212892/109190)

> in short, the period was so far like the present period, that some of its noisiest authorities *insisted that **it be** received*

where a "*that clause*" is used, `insist that`. The question is the part immediately after that, namely, "***it be*** received".

To me, it is easier to understand if that could have stated

> ... some of its noisiest authorities *insisted that **it should/could/would be** received*

On the other hand, I found [lots of people using the expression](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22that%20it%20be%22). Therefor, that would be a commonly used expression that I don't understand.

So, what does "that it be" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "that" is being used as a *conjunction* between two clauses, so you should not isolate that word with just one of the clauses.

Consider this example:

> She said that it was wrong.

She said something. What did she say? She said that it was wrong.

The "authorities insisted" something. What did they insist? They insisted that it be received.

Regarding "it be received" - you probably wouldn't find it so unusual if someone said "it *must* be received". But in examples like yours, a modal verb like "must" is redundant because you have already used the word "insisted" to express necessity. Essentially this means the same.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. As for your example, could I say "She judge that it be wrong"?

Comment: @WXJ96163 No. "She judge" has no tense. It would be "she **judged**", and then you could say "she judged it **to be** wrong".

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. Both expression "she judged that it be wrong" and "she judged it to be wrong" are grammatical and idiomatic, right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Not the first one, no. It makes no sense. Without "to" it places it in the future. You could say "she judged that he be sentenced", because she has judged him, and now he will be sentenced. But something either *is* wrong, or it isn't. Once that is judged, it *is* wrong.